# Flutter/dart - Take screenshot of the entire screen using Flutter?

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, web, screenshot

New to Flutter these days and came across something which I would like your help to tackle.

[Flutter/dart] Is there a way to take screenshot of the entire screen using Flutter?
Looking for a programmatic method to take screenshot of the entire screen, or selected app or an open window. This does not include the Flutter App itself.

Found screen_capturer, but it doesn't work on Web/iOS/Android.

Could you please shed some light for me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for native screenshots? You could try this: https://pub.dev/packages/native_screenshot_ext

Comment: Native Screenshot works on Android and iOS but not on the platforms, right?

Answer (score 0):

you can use [screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot) package.

By using this package you can take screenshot of any widget you want in all flutter supported platforms

Comment: Thank You for your input, I believe, screenshot package can take screenshot of any widget within the Flutter app we create, but nothing outside that, If I am running it on the web, it can take screenshot of that window, nothing outside of that, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, you're correct

Comment: That is not my requirement though.